# How to join in pandas on a.date<=b.date and then taking the only the row where a.date is max?

Tags: python, pandas, join

I am trying to join two dataframes by ID and Date. However, the date criteria is that the a.date<=b.date and in case a.date has a many results, then taking the max value (but still <b.date). How would I do that?

```
Dataframe A (cumulative sales table)
ID| date       | cumulative_sales
1 | 2020-01-01 | 10
1 | 2020-01-03 | 15
1 | 2021-01-02 | 20

Dataframe B
ID| date       | cumulative_sales (up to this date, how much was purchased for a given ID?)
1 | 2020-05-01 | 15
```

In SQL, I would do a join by a.date<=b.date, then I would next do a dense_rank() and take the max value within that partition for each ID. Not sure how to approach this with Pandas. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
dfA = dfA.sort_values(['ID', 'date']).join(
    dfB.set_index('ID'), on='ID', rsuffix='_b').query('date <= date_b').drop(
    columns='date_b').groupby(['ID']).last().reset_index()
```

Explanation:

- sort `dfA` by `ID, date`
- use `join` to join with `dfB` on `ID` and bring the columns from `dfB` in with the suffix `_b`
- use `query` to keep only rows where `dfA.date` <= `dfB.date`
- use `groupby` on `ID` and then `last` to select the row with the highest remaining value of `dfA.date` (i.e., the highest `dfA.date` that is <= `dfB.date` for each `ID`)
- use `reset_index` to convert `ID` from an index level back into a column label

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'date':['2020-01-01','2020-01-03','2020-01-02','2020-01-01','2020-01-03','2020-01-02'], 'cumulative_sales':[10,15,20,30,40,50]})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2], 'date':['2020-05-01','2020-01-01'], 'cumulative_sales':[15,30]})
print(dfA)
print(dfB)

dfA = dfA.sort_values(['ID', 'date']).join(
    dfB.set_index('ID'), on='ID', rsuffix='_b').query(
    'date <= date_b').drop(columns='date_b').groupby(['ID']).last().reset_index()
print(dfA)
```

Input:

```
dfA:

   ID        date  cumulative_sales
0   1  2020-01-01                10
1   1  2020-01-03                15
2   1  2020-01-02                20
3   2  2020-01-01                30
4   2  2020-01-03                40
5   2  2020-01-02                50

dfB:

   ID        date  cumulative_sales
0   1  2020-05-01                15
1   2  2020-01-01                30
```

Output:

```
   ID        date  cumulative_sales  cumulative_sales_b
0   1  2020-01-03                15                  15
1   2  2020-01-01                30                  30
```

Note: I have left `cumulative_sales_b` in place in case you want it. If it's not needed, it can be dropped by replacing `drop(columns='date_b')` with `drop(columns=['date_b', 'cumulative_sales_b'])`.

**UPDATE**:

For fun, if your version of python has the walrus operator `:=` (also known as "conditional assignment" operator), you can do this instead of using `query`:

```py
dfA = (dfA := dfA.sort_values(['ID', 'date']).join(
    dfB.set_index('ID'), on='ID', rsuffix='_b'))[dfA.date <= dfA.date_b].drop(
    columns='date_b').groupby(['ID']).last().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you simply want a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
dfA['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfA['date'])
dfB['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfB['date'])

out = pd.merge_asof(dfB.sort_values(by='date'),
                    dfA.sort_values(by='date'), 
                    on='date', by='ID')
```

Comment: This is a great solution (probably should be the accepted one, as mine is far less elegant). Just a few comments: (1) there's a typo that should be corrected to `on='date'`, (2) it may be desirable for the result to be sorted by `ID`, and (3) this could be done in one line (though some may say that's not any better). The one-liner that occurs to me is: `out = pd.merge_asof(
    dfB.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(dfB.date)).sort_values('date'), 
    dfA.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(dfA.date)).sort_values('date'), 
    on='date', by='ID').sort_values('ID')`

Answer (score 1):

We can do `merge`

```
out = df1.merge(df2, on = 'ID', suffixes = ('','_x')).\
            query('date<=date_x').sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('ID',keep='last')[df1.columns]
Out[272]: 
   ID          date  cumulative_sales
1   1   2020-01-03                 15
```